# How can I sort group_by option for entityType field in formbuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am grouping my $entity output with frombuilder:

```
$options['group_by'] = function ($entity) {
    if ($entity->getCategory() != null) {
        return $entity->getCategory()->getName();
    } else {
        return "all";
    }
};
```

This is the output of my dropdown:

```
  colors
     blue
     red
     green
  all
     colors
     friends
  friends
     elephant
     monkey
```

But I like the groups to be sorted alphabetically. The output I expect is:

```
all
     colors
     friends
colors
     blue
     red
     green
friends
     elephant
     monkey
```

I could not find any hint to do this in the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by
Is there any chance to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the options by the group name via a custom QueryBuilder:

```php
$builder->add('...', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => YourEntity::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('entity')
            ->leftJoin('entity.category', 'category')
            ->addSelect('CASE WHEN entity.category IS NULL THEN \'all\' ELSE category.name END AS HIDDEN category_name')
            ->orderBy('category_name', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('entity.name', 'ASC');
    },
    'group_by' => ...,
]);
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder

Comment: I tried your code I get an error `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 90: Error: Expected known function, got 'IFNULL'`   also I am using query builder already, I am ordering like this `>orderBy('entity.name', 'ASC', 'entity.category.name', 'ASC');` because also name has to be ordered alphabetically.

Comment: I've edited my post, please test again.
(I'm using `IFNULL()` from https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions, and I have forgotten that it is not a default function in doctrine. Replaced by `CASE WHEN` now.)  

You should sort by category name first, and by entity name second.